# Double ls sorting rules

Tags: ls

I'd like `ls` to sort

1. By filename (case *insensitive*)
2. By "version" (`-v`)

I often have directories in which there are some numbered files like

```
1-FileA
2-FileB
...
9-FileC
10-FileD
...
19-FileE
20-FileF
```

and so forth. Now, with the `-v` option I'm able to make `ls` sort by the number prepended to the file name (so I see `1-FileA`, ..., `9-FileC`, `10-FileD`  instead of `1-FileA`, `10-FileD`, ..., `19-FileE`, `2-FileB`) and the option `--group-directories-first` allows me to list directories first, but the sort is not case insensitive, instead, it shows directories that begin with a (sequence of) uppercase letter(s) and then directories that have only lowercase letters and then files with the same criterion.

I'd like to order them regardless the "casing" of the file/directory name. Is there a way to achieve this without using the `sort` command (which would get rid of the coloring produced by the `ls` option `--color=auto`)?

EDIT: I'm using Debian GNU/Linux and the output of `locale` is

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=it_IT.UTF8
LC_TIME=it_IT.UTF8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=it_IT.UTF8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=it_IT.UTF8
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT=it_IT.UTF8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Thanks in advance.